# Changing from string to Int in Datatable with .Select statement cannot convert string to int

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, datarow

I have a DataTable that I clone and I end up adding in a lot of model backed properties.

One thing I noticed when I was doing sandbox/playground work with dotnetfiddle.net was that I was not using my important ID column which is of data type  int.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/dRrlVu

Now that I have added it in

I'm changing from

```
foreach (string id in distinctRows)
```

to

```
foreach (Int32 id in distinctRows)
```

I really do NOT understand this line of code at all

```
var rows = dt.Select("ID = '" + id + "'");
```

Of course now that it went from a string to an int that is going to be a problem, but how do I even fix it.

```
public int id { get; set; }
```

Code that is in the dotnetfiddle  https://dotnetfiddle.net/dRrlVu

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof (int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof (string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Result", typeof (string));
    dt.Columns.Add("other", typeof (string));
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "John", "1,2,3,4,5", "b");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mary ", "5,6,7,8", "d");
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "John", "6,7,8,9", "a");
    DataTable dtRsult = dt.Clone();


    var distinctRows = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "ID").Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(k => k[0] + "").ToArray();

    //foreach (string id in distinctRows)
    foreach (Int32  in distinctRows)
    {
        var rows = dt.Select("ID = '" + id + "'");
        //var rows = dt.Select("ID = '" + id + "'");
        string value = "";
        string other = "";
        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
        {
            value += row["Result"] + ",";
            other += row["other"];
        }

        value = value.Trim(',');
        dtRsult.Rows.Add(id, value, other);
        value = "";
        other = "";
    }

    var output = dtRsult;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtRsult.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dr[0] + " --- " + dr[1] + "---- " + dr[2]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify the exact problem that you're trying to solve?  I *think* you're getting an error with your `.Select()` call that it can't convert the string to an int.  But that is not clear from your question.

Comment: BTW: `"ID = '" + id + "'"` works whether `id` is a `string` or an `int`, the compiler will automatically call `.ToString()` on the `int` for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of your code

```
....Select(k => k[0] + "").....
```

Takes the first column of the enumerated row (the ID field of type integer) and use the + operator with an empty string. [The + operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a63xkz.aspx) when applied to an integer and a string transforms everything in a string. The resulting string is then added to the enumeration to be returned and transformed in an array

So the resulting  `var distinctRows` is just an array of strings.
Of course you can't use a foreach with an Int32 to traverse your collection of strings

If you remove that operator and the empty string your code will work

```
var distinctRows = dt.DefaultView
                     .ToTable(true, "ID")
                     .Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                     .Select(k => k[0])
                     .ToArray();
```